# Capture followed by Digits: Replace Syntax? (Dreamweaver)

Tags: regex, replace, dreamweaver

When you address a regex capture, things can get tricky when digits follow the capture. In PCRE, I can write

```
${1}000
```

to substitute the capture of Group 1 followed by three zeroes.

Does anyone know the equivalent syntax in Dreamweaver replace operations, if any?

If we had a series of "A"s instead of zeroes, we could use:

```
$1AAAA
```

But these:

```
$10000
${1}0000
```

do not work.

I believe the regex flavor is ECMAScript. Just cannot find the information.
This may not be addressed in the syntax. If so, that would be good to know.

Thank you!

Edit: I should add that this is not matter of life and death as I have a number of grep tools at my fingertips. I would just like to know.

Comment: Are you sure that the replacement string `$10000` doesn't work? The JavaScript (ECMAScript) `String.replace()` method works correctly for me. When the regex pattern has less than 10 capture groups, the engine knows that only `$1` makes sense and it works as expected.

Comment: Ah, ridgerunner, my recursive hero... Great to hear from you again! Yes, that's why I'm asking the question. :) At least in my version of DW (CS5.5), the replace with $180 drops a literal $180, while ${1}80 drops ${1}80. Wishing you a fun day.

Comment: Sorry but I don't have access to DreamWeaver. Although one possible solution is to encode the char following the `$1` with something like: `$1\x30000` or `$1\u0030000` or `$1&#48;000`, (if one of these is allowed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dreamweaver's regular expression find and replace is supposed to be based on JavaScript's implementation of RegExp. You should be able to just use $1000 in the replacement text. However, like you've found, the replacement groups ($ + group number) are not properly recognized when the replacement text has digits immediately after the grouping token.

FWIW: I've logged a bug on this at http://adobe.ly/DWwish

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for reporting the bug.